# Overflow:hidden for Ext.Window for ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I'm thinking of using Ext.Window for my project. I was wondering whether it is possible to have an Ext.Window to partially shown in the Browser window?

Like half of the window got stuck out of the browser window from the left.

Cheers, 
Mickey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Run this example, click the button to launch an `Ext.Window`, then drag it partially out of view.

But if you uncomment the `constrain: true` configuration, it will *not* be allowed to be dragged outside of the browser view.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ext-3.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script src="ext-3.1.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script src="ext-3.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script>
      Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'ext-3.1.1/resources/images/default/s.gif';
      Ext.onReady(function(){
        var p = new Ext.Panel({
          renderTo: 'panel',
          html: 'panel',
          tbar: [{
            text: 'Show a Modal Window',
            handler: function() {
              new Ext.Window({
                //constrain: true,
                title: 'Title',
                html: 'Window',
                modal: true
              }).show();
            }
          }]
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the details of what you are doing.  Yes, you could position the window as needed programmatically and set `overflow:hidden` on the document body to prevent scrollbars (if that's what you mean).  Or you could hide only the x overflow and still scroll vertically.